# Do the benefits of Resin/Quercus outweigh the overhead?

Tags: java, php

Lately, I've been looking more and more into Resin + Quercus as a technology to develop an application of mine.

The reason I started looking into it was that this application has high reporting needs, a lot of which cannot (or realistically, should not) be created in real-time.  Java would offer a nice backend to queue and generate reports. Also, with Quercus I would be able to develop my data models in Hibernate, and use them "from PHP", thus effectively stretching these models across front and back-end. This same concept would also apply to any front/back-end common business logic, which could be developed in Java libraries.

Now, the downside is that whichever front-end (PHP) MVC Framework I choose (my goal was Symfony 2), it is unlikely to work without some heavy modification, if it can work at all. Quercus is a pretty close implementation of PHP, and is supposed to be compatible with PHP5.3, so namespaces and closures SHOULDN'T be a problem, but when I tried to run an existing Symfony 1.4 app, I failed miserably.

So, my question to you is, do you think the benefits of Resin + Quercus outweigh the overhead of using a not-so-perfect/stable implementation of PHP? If this were your application, and your goal was and end-product, rather than educational purposes, what would you decide?

Comment: I believe WordPress runs on Quercus.

Comment: Indeed WordPress does. Quercus has a list of applications known to run in the Quercus environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive research, I've decided to answer my own question.

I've found Resin + Quercus to be under-developed, and poorly supported.  Browsing through their [issue tracker](http://bugs.caucho.com/view_all_bug_page.php), there are clearly year old issues that are still marked as 'new' with no acknowledgement.

Also, although Quercus is OSS, Caucho has [expressed that no community code/patches will be accepted](http://forum.caucho.com/showthread.php?t=6066).

That said, I believe that the minor benefits that one might get from using Quercus PHP would be extremely outweighed by the lack of support and compatibility with production PHP setups.

Comment: I'm not sure your interpretation of the test case thread is correct.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - Can you elaborate on that? Why do you think that?

Comment: The thread you refer to just show that Caucho will not make their TCK public, but are willing to accept testcases.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - ah, yes. You can submit a test case to demonstrate the problem and how it should work, but you cannot submit any code or patch to the problem. And from what I've seen, submitting a bug with a test-case doesn't seem to push anything along.

Comment: probably not, but in any case that is not what you wrote, and I objected to.